# Post Image on Instagram with API using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, instagram, instagram-api

I am building a Asp.net C# application i want to post the user uploaded picture directly to Instagram, but after a quick search i can not found any function in the API somebody help me how to post image on instagram wall by C# code

Below Code I can Get Access Token

```
    private void Authentication()
      {      
                string rest = string.Empty;
                GlobusInstagramLib.Authentication.ConfigurationIns config = new GlobusInstagramLib.Authentication.ConfigurationIns("https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["callbackurl"], "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", "https://api.instagram.com/v1/", "");
                oAuthInstagram _api = oAuthInstagram.GetInstance(config);
                rest = _api.AuthGetUrl("likes+comments+basic+relationships");
                Response.Redirect(rest); 
       }
```

// Call back Url

```
 public ActionResult Instagram()
    {
        string code = (String)Request.QueryString["code"];
        oAuthInstagram objInsta = new oAuthInstagram();
        GlobusInstagramLib.Authentication.ConfigurationIns configi = new GlobusInstagramLib.Authentication.ConfigurationIns("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["callbackurl"], "http://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", "https://api.instagram.com/v1/", "");
        oAuthInstagram _api = new oAuthInstagram();
        _api = oAuthInstagram.GetInstance(configi);
        AccessToken access = new AccessToken();
        access = _api.AuthGetAccessToken(code);
        string accessToken = access.access_token;
        string id =access.user.id;
        ViewBag.accessToken = accessToken;`enter code here`
        ViewBag.Uid = id;
        return View();     
    }
```

Below Code i have get Access Token and Profile ID
How To Post Image ? some body tall me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot upload photos to Instagram through the API. From Instagram's API documentation https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/:

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a
>   conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:
>
> - Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos from within the app.
> - We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to control what comes into the
>     Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working on ways to
>     ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience on our
>     platform.